# Работа с текстом

Tags: pascal

Надо из файла 1 в файл 2 перебросить город, до которого лететь менее 4 часов. У меня ошибка где-то с типами... т.е. он читает в ТХТ время и не может его сравнить с обычным числом либо не читает время. Как это исправить? Вот текст проги

```
program lab3; 
uses crt; 
var 
time:0..5; 
gorod:real; 
fin, fout:text; 
begin 
clrscr; 
assign(fin,'1.txt'); 
assign(fout,'2.txt'); 
reset(fin); 
rewrite(fout); 
writeln(fout, 'gorod do kotorogo letet menee 4 chasov'); 
repeat 
readln(fin,gorod,time); 
until eof(fin) or (time<=4); 
if eof(fin) then writeln('takogo net') 
else writeln(fout, gorod, time);

close(fin); 
close(fout); 
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Компилятора нет под рукой, к сожалению, но, попробуйте переписать основную логическую часть вашей программы, чтобы было понятнее, что происходит. *И если ошибки все еще есть, то стоит подебажить и попытаться понять в чем дело.*

```
var time:Integer;
    gorod:Real; { Непонятно, почему Real, а не String, например, но почему бы и нет }

{ ... }

repeat
    readln(fin, gorod, time);
    if time in [1..4] then
    begin
        writeln(fout, gorod, time);
        break;
    end
until eof(fin)

{ Если у нас все-таки случился конец файла, то значит ничего не нашли }
writeln(fout, 'Takogo net.');

{ ... }
```